# test that argument looks like a date

Tags: regex, bash, cygwin

I'm modifying a script used to test a report writer. The report writer takes optional --from and --to flags to specify the start and end dates. I'd like to modify the script function that starts up the report writer so that its date arguments are also optional.

Sadly, there are already optional arguments to the function, so I'm trying to test whether an argument is in the right format for a date (we use nn/nn/nnnn).

So, I'm echoing the candidate string and checking with grep whether it is in the correct format. Except it doesn't work.

Here is an extract from the function

```
    # If the next argument looks like a date, consume it and use it to define
    # the report start date

    looksLikeDate=$(echo $1 | grep -e '[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')
    echo from -
    echo \$1: \"$1\"
    echo looksLikeDate: \"$looksLikeDate\"
    if [ -n $looksLikeDate ]
    then
        echo "-n: true"
        FROMFLAG="--from $1"
        shift 1
    else
        echo "-n : false"
        FROMFLAG=""
    fi

    # If the next argument looks like a date, consume it and use it to define
    # the report end date

    looksLikeDate=$(echo $1 | grep -e '[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')
    echo to -
    echo \$1: \"$1\"
    echo looksLikeDate: \"$looksLikeDate\"
    if [ -n $looksLikeDate ]
    then
        echo "-n: true"
        TOFLAG="--to $1"
        shift 1
    else
        echo "-n: false"
        TOFLAG=""
    fi
```

...and here is the output with dates...

```
from -
$1: "09/02/2018"
looksLikeDate: "09/02/2018"
-n: true
to -
$1: "09/02/2018"
looksLikeDate: "09/02/2018"
-n: true
```

...and without...

```
from -
$1: ""
looksLikeDate: ""
-n: true
to -
$1: ""
looksLikeDate: ""
-n: true
```

...what have I missed? I'd expect that since `looksLikeDate` is demonstrable empty `[ -n $looksLikeDate ]` would return `false` and the code would go down the `else` path of the `if` statement.

Update:

Since posting, it occurs to me that the easiest thing is to not to look at the arguments in the function and get callers to pass the `--from` and `--to` with the arguments so that I can simply pass `$*` to the report writer as is done for the existing optional arguments.

Thank you very much for reading; I'm still curious as to why the posted code doesn't work.

Comment: Run your script with `set -x` to see the values of variables. Also, quote all your variables – use shellcheck to point out common flaws.

Comment: You should also show how you call this; we can't know what's in `$1`.

Comment: You're processing `$1` twice, which – at least in this excerpt – is the same variable. Are you not showing some parameter manipulations?

Comment: I believe I've included all the relevant code (apart from the calls). Did you overlook the `shift 1` after setting `FROMFLAG` so that I've moved on to the next function argument.?

Comment: Ah, I did indeed not see that. To be able to tell you why this doesn't work, you have to show how `$1` is populated, though. Ideally, in a way so people can reproduce what you're seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're not quoting your variables! [Use more quotes!](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)

So here's what's happening: when Bash sees

```
[ -n $looksLikeDate ]
```

it performs parameter expansion, glob expansion, quote removal, etc., and finally sees this (I put one token on each line):

```
[
-n
]
```

and you see that the `$looksLikeDate` part is missing because the parameter `$looksLikeDate` expands to the empty string before the quote removal step. Then Bash executes the builtin `[`, and with the closing `]`, this is equivalent to the following command:

```
test -n
```

Now looking at the [reference manual for the `test` builtin](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#index-test), you'll read:

> 1 argument
>
> The expression is true if, and only if, the argument is not null.

And here, the argument is `-n`, hence not nil, hence the expression is true.

So remember:

> **Use more quotes! quote *all* your variable expansions!**

This specific line should look like:

```
[ -n "$looksLikeDate" ]
```

Another possibility is to use the `[[` keyword:

```
[[ -n $looksLikeDate ]]
```

But anyway, quote all your expansion!

Also, you don't need the external tool `grep`, you can use Bash's internal regex engine or, better yet:

```
if [[ $1 = [[:digit:]][[:digit:]]/[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]/[[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]] ]]; then
```

which is a bit long, so use a variable:

```
date_pattern="[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]/[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]/[[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]]"
if [[ $1 = $date_pattern ]]; then
```

(and here you *mustn't* quote the right hand side `$date_pattern`).